# Trying to identify an episode of a 1980's Sci-Fi TV Series. Perhaps Amazing Stories, Outer Limits?

Tags: time-travel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for an old SF tv short story about blue men staging the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/looking-for-an-old-sf-tv-short-story-about-blue-men-staging-the-future)

The premise is similar to the logic used in The Langoliers, in that time is constructed, & deconstructed, but living beings are simply passing through it, like from one scene to another in a movie.

In the opening scene, a couple wakes in their bedroom, to the sound of people & furniture moving.  When they go to investigate, they find workmen, donned in blue work suits & baseball hats, with no visible faces, working in their home.  All attempts at communicating with them fail.

Realizing that they are unable to subdue the blue workers, the homeowners leave their home for help, only to find that they are the only people in town; that is… besides the blue workers. Eventually they run across an individual, who seems to be running things.  I believe it was an older black actor (perhaps Cab Calloway), donned in a yellow suit.  On one arm, he has a series of watches, to help him keep track of the past, present, & future time.

After explaining the premise of the passage of time, as building blocks, he takes them to another time (future?), simply by motioning, like he’s pulling a curtain aside, and they walk through.  It’s still the same place, just a future moment in time, where construction has not been completed.  He continues to explain how they weren’t supposed to ‘see’ how time works.  Subsequently, they can’t be allowed to return to the main stream or flow of time.

Somehow they manage to get away from the ‘time keeper’, and hide in the ticket booth of a movie theater, awaiting the approach of present time.  Unfound by the ‘time keeper’, a rushing sound is heard; seemingly the approach of present time.  Once time catches up to the couple, they rejoice in being back with humanity, and the normal flow of time.  As the ending scene closes, the couple discovers a blue pipe wrench, apparently left behind by the blue workmen, proving what they had experienced was not a dream

Comment: [The Miniseries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Langoliers_(TV_miniseries)) ?

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate of [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9861/3025).

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is the 80s Twilight Zone episode ["A Matter of Minutes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Matter_of_Minutes)