# Movie or TV series episode where workers prepare the reality in the future for people coming from the past

Tags: episode-identification, story-identification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for an old SF tv short story about blue men staging the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/looking-for-an-old-sf-tv-short-story-about-blue-men-staging-the-future)

A guy suddenly jumps into the future, and sees some workers prepearing the reality out of nothing for the people that comes from the past.

It could be late 80s or early 90s, it was in full color.

Comment: I think this is a repeat of a recent questions. Searching...

Comment: Here we go: [Looking for an old SF tv short story about blue men staging the future](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9861/231). If it is a duplicate.

Comment: @dmckee Yup, I bet that's the episode he is thinking of.

Comment: it's a duplicate, couldn't find it before posting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly what you describe, but I bet you mean an episode from the Twilight Zone: [A Matter of Minutes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Matter_of_Minutes).

The couple of protagonists are "stuck" in time and get to see the workmen who tear down the world once it's in the past, and who rebuild it in the future.

If you remember blue workmen, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related Miniseries from 1995: [The Langoliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Langoliers_%28TV_miniseries%29).