# 1950s SF short story where the streetlights are cued, objects don't exist until needed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What is the title of a 1950s SF short story where the streetlights are cued, objects don't exist until needed when hero approaches?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This is a very brief description though. Please take a look at [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and if you can think of any more details about the story or where you read it, please [edit] your question to add those in.

Comment: Welcome to SFF and thank you for taking the advice previously given to you and asking this as a question itself! Further to this can you remember anything else at all about this short story that you could [edit] into the post? For example, what the overarching plot was? You say hero, can you expand more on that? Can you remember what anthology this may have appeared in?

Comment: What does "the streetlights are cued" mean? That they only turn on when you approach them?

Comment: Is it "Yesterday was Monday" by Theodore Sturgeon?  The Twilight Zone based an episode ("A Matter of Minutes") off it. See also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181814/man-wakes-up-too-soon-and-scene-isnt-set

Comment: Sounds thematically similar to "They", a short story by Heinlein. Protagonist seems to be extremely solipsistic - but it turns out there's an army of people constructing the environment around him. "The Truman Show", only a half century earlier.

Comment: Or do you mean "queued" as in waiting to appear, like queued computer code?

Comment: I suspect Bob means "cued" as in "turned on as if on cue when the hero approaches".

Comment: @JohnSG That's what I thought of first. You should post an answer.