# Creating the future in boxcars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, tv, time

I'm trying to find the title of a sci-fi short story I either read or saw on TV - the plot is generally about possibly invisible (I might be wrong about that) people who build the future by re-creating our surroundings in boxcars on a train.

Comment: The famous story about the people who build the future, minute by minute, is Theodore Sturgeon's ["Yesterday Was Monday"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45034), which was the basis for the Twilight Zone episode ["A Matter of Minutes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Matter_of_Minutes), and was the answer to [this old question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/looking-for-an-old-sf-tv-short-story-about-blue-men-staging-the-future). But I'm not sure there were any boxcars in it, so maybe you're thinking of a different story.

Comment: Yes. It was A Matter of Minutes. There are no boxcars - they are blue moving trucks.

Comment: How do you know? Are you Laura?

Comment: Yes. I'm Laura. Thanks for your answer!  I look forward to reading the original story as well.

Comment: Please post under your original account. If you're having accessing the old one you can merge them; http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: In "A Matter of Minutes", someone uses the boxcars as an analogy.  I remember it that way, and also http://www.steveandmarta.com/a%20matter%20of%20minutes/ntz_matter_of_minutes_synopsis.html says so.