# Building minutes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Does anyone know a SF TV short story in which there were blue men who helped "stage" our world- at least the parts we saw, on a minute by minute basis.

So, at each minute, everyone would be in the "world" that was built for that minute, then they would go on to the next "minute world". The blue men were in the future minutes building most of reality, but only the parts that would be looked at at that minute.

And they were in the past tearing down all the previously lived minutes.

It was kind of a behind the scenes look at why when you set your keys down and come back to them, they aren't there. Then you look again a few minutes later and they are there. The reason in the show was that the blue men building that minute forgot to include your keys, but the next group got it right.
Someone else had [asked this question also](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/looking-for-an-old-sf-tv-short-story-about-blue-men-staging-the-future?rq=1), but the answers provided did not help me.

Comment: A link to the earlier question would really help, as it may include slightly different details *and* people can see any suggestions to the previous questions that were not correct. So I've edited in the one from the "related" sidebar.

Comment: Now that I see that the one I linked on your behalf has an accepted answer, it would really help if you explained how the story you are looking for differs from the one in the answer to that previous question.

Comment: When you say "the answers provided did not help me", did you watch the Twilight Zone episode mentioned in the accepted answer, titled "A Matter of Minutes"? That really sounds like what you're describing...the episode is online [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKbylBQ0igk) if you want to see it, the blue people responsible for constructing and deconstructing each moment make their first appearance at [2 minutes 23 seconds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKbylBQ0igk&t=2m23s).

Comment: This one is very close to it. But the one that I remember, a man had lost his watch and was looking for it. The blue men finally made it, so the man said he found it. The blue man that made the mistake was scolded by his boss. Maybe this was some type of small "movie" clip that I saw somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely the Twilight Zone episode, [A Matter of Minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Matter_of_Minutes)

Closing narration:

> Time, a handy fiction to explain why everything doesn't happen all at once. Or maybe we're the fiction, moving minute by minute...through the Twilight Zone.

The couple ends up with a blue wrench as a souvenir of slipping into the loophole in time.